# Application is not starting up after spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure dependency upgrade

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-actuator

I've recently upgraded the spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure version from 2.2.4.RELEASE to 2.7.11. After upgrading the version the application is not starting up. And it is showing the below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
    - org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Below is the Application.java file:

```
import com.model.ModelConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.EnableCircuitBreaker;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

/**
 * Launches this application using the Spring Boot framework.
 */
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@Import({ModelConfiguration.class, UIConfiguration.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableAsync
public class Application
{
    public static final String LOGOUT_URL = "/logout.html";
    /**
     * Entry point
     */
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration` [exists in Spring Boot 2.7](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.11/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/security/servlet/ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.java) so it's not clear why the compiler thinks it does not. I would guess that you have a corrupted `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure` jar on the classpath that is preventing its classes from being read. If that's the case purging your build system's local cache should help.

Comment: Tried multiple ways to remove the cache:

1. Restarted IDE with Invalidate Cache

2. mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -U

Still getting error:


```java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
 - org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration```

Comment: Neither of those will purge Maven's local cache. For example, `-U` will just update snapshots but you don't have any snapshot dependencies. Try `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` instead.